# PHP: Illegal offset type while generating an array from xml

Tags: php, arrays, xml

Why am I getting `Illegal offset type` error while trying to build an array?

```
function tassi_parser() {
    $xml=simplexml_load_file('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml');
    foreach($xml->Cube->Cube->Cube as $tmp) {
        $results[$tmp['currency']] = $tmp['rate'];
    };
    return $results;
};
```

`$tmp['currency']` correctly contains a string that should be used as key so i can't understand what is the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simplexml_load_file return SimpleXMLElement and every xml element will be an object. Therefore, the type of your $tmp in foreach is "object" (not string), so you need to cast it to string as follows:

```
(string)$tmp['currency']
```

You could use the gettype function to retrieve the type of something: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php

Comment: @Mariano What? Seriously?! I wrote that 15 minutes before this answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast it to string like this:

```
$results[(string)$tmp['currency']] = (string)$tmp['rate'];
```

Also the `;` at the end of the foreach and the function isn't necessary!